# How to preserve decimal values when converting POSIXct to character?

Tags: r, posixct

```r
> t <- Sys.time()
> ct <- as.character(t)
> t - as.POSIXct(ct)
Time difference of 0.4370408 secs
```

The above example indicates that precision is lost when converting POSIXct to character.

How to preserve the exact value when converting to character so that when I convert back to POSIXct from character I get the original value?

Comment: It is often wise to give your objects not the same name as a function; see `?t`.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the option `digits.secs` to 6 (its maximum value).

```
options(digits.secs = 6)

t <- Sys.time()
ct <- as.character(t)
t - as.POSIXct(ct)
```

```
Time difference of 0 secs
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to mess with the global options?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format` with `%OS6`, to give seconds in digits, but still there will be sometimes a difference:

```
t <- Sys.time()
ct <- format(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6")
t - as.POSIXct(ct)
#Time difference of 0 secs
```